# Как одновременно обходить два масива?

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Я новичок в PHP. Делаю свой импорт/экспорт данных Excel.
У меня есть вложенный массив с данными такого вида:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => 1
            [full_name] => Иванов Иван Иванович
            [date] => 1995:07:02
            [adress] => г. Москва
            [passport] => ВС212928
            [childs] => да
            [salary] => 15,000.00 ₽
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => 2
            [full_name] => Петров Петр Петрович
            [date] => 1993:01:01
            [adress] => г. Москва
            [passport] => АС212121
            [childs] => нет
            [salary] => 20,000.00 ₽
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [number] => 3
            [full_name] => Сидоров Николай Николеевич
            [date] => 1994:02:05
            [adress] => г. Москва
            [passport] => ВК199894
            [childs] => да
            [salary] => 1,200,000.00 ₽
        )
}
```

Эти данные я вставляю в Excel, но сейчас это работает слишком жестко, с привязкой на количество рядов в таблице. Вот так

```
     foreach ($rows as $row) {
         $active_sheet->setCellValue('A' . $count, $row['number']);
         $active_sheet->setCellValue('B' . $count, $row['full_name']);
         $active_sheet->setCellValue('C' . $count, $row['date']);
         $active_sheet->setCellValue('D' . $count, $row['adress']);
         $active_sheet->setCellValue('E' . $count, $row['passport']);
         $active_sheet->setCellValue('F' . $count, $row['childs']);
         $active_sheet->setCellValue('G' . $count, $row['salary']);

         $count = $count + 1;
     }
```

Я создал массив с алфавитом

```
$alphabet = range('A','Z')
```

Как я могу динамически подставлять буквы алфавитаи значения из моего массива с данными в метод **setCellValue()**

Пытаюсь сделать так, но не работает, т.к у меня имеется вложенность

```
    foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
         $active_sheet->setCellValue($alphabet[$key] . $count, $row[$key]);
         $count = $count + 1;
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$alphabet = range('A','Z');

foreach ($rows as $idx => $row) {
    // счетчик для алфавита
    // 0 => A
    // на каждой итерации начинается с 0
    $alphaCount = 0; 
    // перебираем массив данных для записи ($row)
    foreach($row as $value) {
        // для каждого массива записываем букву алфавита ($alphabet[$alphaCount])
        // и индекс текущего массива ($idx) как ключ, а значение передаем напрямую
        $active_sheet->setCellValue($alphabet[$alphaCount] . $idx, $value);
        // увеличиваем значение счетчика алфавита, чтобы для следующего значения
        // текущего массива ($row) брать следующую букву алфавита
        $alphaCount++;
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel позволяет использовать нотацию не только `A1` и т.п., но и использованием числовых индексов столбца и строки.

Используемая вами библиотека PhpSpreadsheet также имеет встроенные методы для работы с индексами - [`setCellValueByColumnAndRow`](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/). Так что код сводится к банальному

```
foreach($rows as $rIdx => $row){
    foreach($row as $colIdx => $col){
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1 + $colIdx, $rowIdx, $col);
    } 
}
```

Comment: @splash58 они это кто?

Comment: @splash58 ничего не могу сказать по этому поводу. Не знаю у кого какие были сложности с обратной совместимостью.

Comment: Забудьте, это про PHPExcel